# Is there a way to see what the current value and change it for the socket buffer size used by Apache Http Client?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Apache HttpClient 4.3.x and was wondering if there's a way too see what is the current value for the socket buffer size used by it to send/receive data and if it's possible for me to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a way to see the current value, but if you haven't provided a `ConnectionConfig` when building your `HttpClient`, it uses `ConnectionConfig.DEFAULT` which has a `bufferSize` of `8192`.

You can specify a custom buffer size when building your `HttpClient`. For example,

```
int bufferSize = 42;
ConnectionConfig config = ConnectionConfig.custom().setBufferSize(bufferSize).build();

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                    .setDefaultConnectionConfig(config)
                                    .build();
```